# C Dynamic Memory vs Stack Memory Variables

Tags: c, arrays, memory, memory-management

When a C array is created using malloc, the array is stored in the heap, and when a C array is created statically it is stored in the stack. However, what happens if you return an element of a C array initialized statically from a function? My wording may be strange, so here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char getStaticElement();
char getDynamicElement();

int main() {
    char dynamicElement = getDynamicElement();
    char staticElement = getStaticElement();
    printf("Dynamic Element: %c\n", dynamicElement);
    printf("Static Element: %c\n", staticElement);
    return 0;

}
char getStaticElement() {
    char staticArray [] = {'a','b','c'};
    return staticArray[1]; // returns b
}
char getDynamicElement() {
    char * dynamicArray = malloc(sizeof(char)*4);
    dynamicArray [0] ='a';
    dynamicArray [1] ='b';
    dynamicArray [2] ='c';
    dynamicArray [3] ='\0';
    return dynamicArray[1]; // returns b
}
```

So where is staticElement in memory? Is staticArray cleared off the stack  because the function has finished, or is it still on the Stack because and element of staticArray has been returned? 
NOTE: I know I did not free dynamic array, and am leaking memory, this is just an example and not meant to be used.

Comment: The C standard does not require a stack or a heap. What do you expect? And Why?

Comment: I am wondering why I do not have to worry about the location of staticElement in memory despite the fact that the function getStaticElement has ended

Comment: Also, I did not know the C Standard does not require a stack or a heap, my apologies, my professor told us that C Program variables are stored in the stack if they are not created dynamically(malloc, calloc, realloc ...) @Olaf

Comment: @Turtle Pretty much everyone uses the terms "stack" and "heap" for things like this. The C spec uses the terms "automatic storage duration" and "dynamic storage duration," which are more technical, more portable, but also less frequently used colloquially.

Comment: Your professor talks about a specific implementation. Yet alread that is wrong with moden compilers which use advanced register allocation even to hold and pass (small) arrays and `struct`s in registers. He might want to update his knowledge from the 80ies to date. (I know such tutors very well). Things are far from being that simple as they used to be.

Comment: @Olaf does this mean that a small char * created without malloc can be returned by the function? Say: `char* p = "RETURNME"; return p;`

Comment: @Olaf and is there a place I can go to readup on advanced register allocation?

Comment: C is strictly pass by value. So you don't return the pointer, only its value. And asking for external information is off-topic on SO. But I heard about such a thingie called "search provider" and a website called "google". Maybe they can help you. ;-)

Comment: I was not aware it was off topic, it was just general curiosity that drove me to ask the question. Also I have actually heard of that thingie called "google" which other than a small wikipedia article didn't give me much help hence the question asked to an embedded systems professional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, if you return a `char` or `int` from a function, you're returning a *copy* of that value from the function, not the actual object itself. In other words, if you return an element of an array you declared as a local variable, you're really returning a *copy* of that array element, so even when the original array is destroyed there's no worry that you somehow "lose" that array element. Similarly, if you return an element of an array allocated with `malloc`, you're returning a copy of the array element rather than the element itself. This is why you're not getting garbage values back in the above code.

The value that's handed back is not necessarily stored in either the stack or the heap. It's usually stored in a register somewhere. From the language's point of view it has *automatic storage duration* and so will get cleaned up automatically. Since you're storing that value in a local variable, it will be stored on the stack (or, more technically, it has automatic storage duration), but that's because you put it in a local variable and has nothing to do with the fact that it was originally in a dynamically- or statically-allocated array.

That said, you *are* leaking memory, since you never `free` the data that you allocated with `malloc`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I know it is leaking memory, this was just an example program that I had not intention of running. I wanted to to be clear that I was returning a dynamically allocated element since my question was somewhat awkwardly worded.

Comment: What about when I return a char * that is not created using malloc? Does that get copied as well?

Comment: In that case, the `char*` is copied, but not the thing it's pointing at. That's why you would need dynamic allocation.